# How to initialize a redux store value from another value in the same store react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I have a component that gets the 'carDataMap' from the redux store. I call the function 'initializeCarDataMap()' (which uses 'selection' from the same store) to set its initial state but run into the error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component.

How can I properly initialize the carDataMap in the redux store which uses values from the same redux store?

```
interface Props {}

export type CarDataMapType = { [car: string]: Data };

export function initializeCarDataMap(): CarDataMapType {
    const initialMap: CarDataMapType = {};
    const initialData = createDefaultData();
    const cars = useSelector((store: StoreState) => store.select).selection.cars;
    for (const car of cars) {
        initialMap[car] = initialData;
    }
    return initialMap;
}

export const CarDataMapWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const carDataMap = useSelector((store: StoreState) => store.select).carDataMap;
    return ();
};

// redux store ---------------------------------

import {
    initializeCarDataMap,
    getSelection,
    CarDataMapType,
};

export interface SelectState {
    selection: Selection;
    carDataMap: CarDataMapType;
}

const initialState: SelectState = {
    selection: getSelection(),
    carDataMap: initializeCarDataMap(),
};

const store = createSlice({
    name: 'select',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCarDataMap: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ car: string; data: Data }>) => {
            state.carDataMap[action.payload.car] = action.payload.data;
        },
    },
});

export default store.reducer;
export const {
    setCarDataMap,
} = store.actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `initializeCarDataMap` is not considered as a React component because it does not start with a capital letter and nor a custom hook because it does not start with the `use` prefix so it is not other than a simple javascript function, therefore you can't call a hook inside it.

> ##### Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> ##### Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about [Building Your Own Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)).

**custum hook:**

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

you just need to rename your function to `useInitializeCarDataMap` for example.